# How to set raspbian to automatically login to google on startup

Tags: raspbian, chromium

I currently have my Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian to the point where it will load with Chromium in kiosk mode. The problem is I need it to load to a work `site.google` site. This can only be done if you are logged into Google first. How can I set it up to login and then load this page? Right now I just get a 404 page when it isn't logged in.

Comment: log in and figure out how to keep it logged in.  lovely nature of "increased security" forces 2fa on even the simplest things these days.  Unless it needs to interact with a database or something on said site, I'd just download the whole thing to the pi and host it...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link to see if that helps.

https://www.element14.com/community/thread/30968/l/booting-to-web-page-in-full-screen-and-auto-log-on-raspberry-pi?displayFullThread=true

Re: Booting to Web Page in Full Screen and auto log on? Raspberry PI
 jflores jflores Jan 24, 2014 6:44 PM (in response to jflores)
Well just figured it out myself.

Here is what I did.

1. I booted into the Raspbian OS.
2. Opened the webrowser, pointed it to the HTTP site.
3. Entered by Credentials, clicked on the save login info, check mark on the webpage.
4. Through ssh: went here: $ sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
5. Edited the info:

## I commented the four lines that were there and added the following lines

@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@midori -e Fullscreen

Now Midori opens up in full screen and auto logs in.